# Primefaces TabView setting null value in controller class upon submit/post

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Here's the scenario:

The user gets a `TabView` component with two different tabs. The first tab contains input fields for an object `Person`. The second tab contains input fields for an object `Book`. On top of this, the second tab displays a list of `Book` objects.

The user is supposed to enter a `Person`'s details first, then to switch to the second tab and to add `Book`s to the list of books. Let's keep it that plain.

The following form is embedded in a template and contains the `TabView`:

```
<h:form id="personBookForm">
    <p:log id="personBookLog"></p:log>
    <p:panel id="personToggleablePanel" toggleable="true" collapsed="false"
        header="Passionate book lovers" toggleSpeed="300">
        <f:facet name="actions">
            <p:commandButton id="savePersonBookButton"
                action="#{personController.savePerson}" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                process="@form" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:tabView id="personBookTabView">

            <p:tab id="personTab" title="Person">
                <p:panelGrid id="personPanelGrid" columns="1">
                    <p:inputText id="nameInput"
                        value="#{personController.currentPerson.name}" />
                    <p:inputText id="surnameInput"
                        value="#{personController.currentPerson.surname}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="bookTab" title="Books">
                <p:panelGrid id="bookPanelGrid">
                    <p:inputText id="titleInput"
                        value="#{personController.currentBook.title}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:dataTable id="bookTable" var="book"
                    value="#{personController.bookList}" rowKey="#{book.id}"
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{personController.currentBook}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:commandButton id="addBookButton" icon="ui-icon-plusthick"
                            style="float:right" />
                        <p:commandButton id="removeBookButton" icon="ui-icon-minusthick"
                            style="float:right" />
                        <p:commandButton id="refreshBookTableButton"
                            icon="ui-icon-refresh" style="float:right;" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Title">
                        <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

The controller class `PersonController.java`:

```
@Named("personController")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonController implements Serializable {

    private Person currentPerson;
    private Book currentBook;

    private List<Book> bookList;

    public PersonController() { }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        currentPerson = new Person();
        currentBook = new Book();
        bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void savePerson() {
        System.out.println("Saving person " + currentPerson);
    }

    public Person getCurrentPerson() {
        return currentPerson;
    }

    public void setCurrentPerson(Person currentPerson) {
        this.currentPerson = currentPerson;
    }

    public Book getCurrentBook() {
        return currentBook;
    }

    public void setCurrentBook(Book currentBook) {
        this.currentBook = currentBook;
    }

    public List<Book> getBookList() {
        return bookList;
    }

    public void setBookList(List<Book> bookList) {
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }
}
```

`Book.java`:

```
public class Book {

    private Long id;
    private String title;

    public Book() { }

    public Book(Long id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

`Person.java`:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    private List<Book> books;

    public Person() { }

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + surname;
    }
}
```

Now, each time the form is submitted, the `Book` object (see `currentBook` in the controller class) is set to null.

What I've found out is that it makes no difference if

- `process=@form` is set or not
- you submit the form on pressing `Enter` or on clicking the `commandButton` (why would it, anyways?!)
- you set values for the `Book` object or not
- you omit the outer panel
- you pull the `form` element inside the `Panel`
- you remove the `Panel`

I was not expecting the `Book` object to be set to `null`.

Everything works as expected if you remove the `dataTable` from the view.

Why is that? Is this the desired behaviour? Could anybody explain what happens, please?

Thanks a lot in advance.